# Solving inequation with parameter

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Let the following inequality

$$4^xa - 2^x + 1 > 0$$

hold for any $x$. How can I find the range of parameter $a$?

The following method doesn't work:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ForAll[x, x ∈ Reals, a*4^x - 2^x + 1 > 0]
Resolve[%, Reals]
Reduce[%, a, Reals]
(* Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods
   available to Reduce. *)
```

The correct answer in the textbook is $a>1/4$.

Comment: Need to help Mathematica. `ForAll[t, t ∈ PositiveReals, a*t^2 - t + 1 > 0] // Resolve`

Comment: Manual substitution can be calculated in one step, but cannot be achieved in one step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't isolate this with `Resolve`, so here is a workaround.

```
Clear[a, x];
sol = Reduce[a*4^x - 2^x + 1 > 0, x, Reals];
Select[sol, FreeQ[x]]
```

> a > 1/4

---

Visualization:

```
vals = {1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2};
Plot[Evaluate[(1 - 2^x + # 4^x ) & /@ vals]
 , {x, -3, 3}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[StringForm["a = ``", #] & /@ vals]
   , {0.2, 0.65}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- Extend my comment to an answer.

```
Clear[range];
range = FunctionRange[2^x, x, t]
ForAll[t, range, a*t^2 - t + 1 > 0] // Resolve
```

> `t > 0`.

> `a > 1/4`.

- Test another example.(compare with the answer by @Syed)

```
{Select[Reduce[a (2^x + 1) (2^x + 2) + 1 > 0, x, Reals], FreeQ[x]], 
 ForAll[t, FunctionRange[2^x, x, t], a (t + 1) (t + 2) + 1 > 0] // 
  Resolve}
```

> `{a >= 0, a >= 0}`.

Answer (score 5):

From `a*4^x - 2^x + 1 > 0` we have `a>(2^x - 1)/4^x`. Therefore, the inequality `4^x a−2x+1>0` hold for any `x` when and only when `a > max((2^x - 1)/4^x)`.
We have

```
Maximize[(2^x - 1)/4^x, x]
```

> {1/4, {x -> 1}}

Thus `a>1/4.`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Reduce[a*4^x - 2^x + 1 > 0 ] // Simplify[#, Element[a, Reals]] &

(* (4^x < 0 && 1 + 4^x a < 2^x) || (4^x > 0 && 1 + 4^x a > 2^x)*)
```

Visualization

```
RegionPlot[a*4^x - 2^x + 1 > 0, {x, -5, 5}, {a, -10, 10},FrameLabel -> {x, a}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

If we substitude `z->2^x` Mathematica's `ForAll` finds the solution

```
ForAll[z, Element[z, PositiveReals], a*z^2 - z + 1 > 0] // Resolve
(* a>1/4 *)
```

Comment: The final result only about `a`, maybe `a>1/4`.  The original question is `ForAll` `x` instead of `Exists` `x`.

Comment: ForAll x belongs to Reals

Comment: Should be `Element[z, PositiveReals]` since `2^x>0` always hold.

Comment: @cvgmt That's correct, tahnks.  I'll modify my answer!